# Meaning of Action in Symfony Controllers

Tags: php, symfony

I am new in Symfony Framework.I start Simple Project in Symfony.I define a function in Controller like

```
public function sampleAction()
{

}
```

What is the meaning of Action here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply a convention (also in other frameworks, such as the ZF) to add the suffix “Action” to the name of those methods in controllers which are directly exposed via routes, to make such actions better distinguishable from other methods.

Technically, “Action“ does not have a meaning at all, i.e.: the method does not behave differently because there is this suffix. You could also define an action method like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // ...
}
```

Symfony does not force you to use that suffix, but I would **strongly** recommend following this convention.

Comment: Actually, with the release of the Symfony 3.0 it is recommended to drop the Action suffix. I am not sure but I think in earlier versions of symfony when writing the action in routing you should have written `index` and it would search for the `indexAction` function.

Comment: What is the source of this information? I can’t recall having read anything about it, and the 3.0 documentation still says “Each action in a controller class is suffixed with Action and is referenced in the routing configuration by the action's name (index)”

Comment: You were very right to question my sources, I decided to double check my sources and I was referring to this slide http://www.slideshare.net/javier.eguiluz/new-symfony-tips-tricks-symfonycon-paris-2015/49 from Javier Eguiluz's presentation, whom I emailed to see what he meant. His conclusion is that you can remove the action suffix if using annotations or controllers as services and you want to make actions shorter. However he doesn't recommend it. And about the second thing I wanted to communicate:  the action suffix is required if using the yaml declaration of routes (so it has some meaning)

Comment: "Don't add the Action suffix to the methods of the controller actions.": https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't be confused by the naming: a controller class is simply a convenient way to group several controllers/actions together. Typically, the controller class will house several controllers/actions (e.g. `updateAction`, `deleteAction`, etc).

[Refer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you have used is camel case representation of the function name

`sampleAction` is the name of the function.

there is no such thing which will differ `sample` or `Action`.