# how to use Symfony methods Action excluding the "Action" word

Tags: symfony, routes

I am currently migrating an existent application to Symfony2 that has about 100 controllers with approximately 8 actions in each controller. All the current Actions are named as follow:

```
public function index(){}
```

However the default naming convention for Symfony is indexAction().
Is it possible to keep all my current actions and tell Symfony to use as it is without the "Action" word after the method name?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You should be able to define routes as normal, but you need to change the way the kernel finds the controller. The best way to do this is to replace/decorate/extends the service 'controller_name_converter'. This is a private service and is injected into the 'controller_resolver' service.

The source code of the class you want to replace is at 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser'.

Basically, the code runs like this. The 'bundle:controller:action' you specified when creating the route is saved in the cache. When a route is matched, that string is given back to the kernel, which in turn calls 'controller_resolver' which calls 'controller_name_resolver'. This class convert the string into a "namespace::method" notation.

Take a look at [decorating services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services) to get an idea of how to do it.

Here is an untested class you can work with

```
class ActionlessNameParser
{
    protected $parser;

    public function __construct(ControllerNameParser $parser)
    {
        $this->parser = $parser;
    }

    public function parse($controller)
    {
        if (3 === count($parts = explode(':', $controller))) {
            list($bundle, $controller, $action) = $parts;
            $controller = str_replace('/', '\\', $controller);

            try {
                // this throws an exception if there is no such bundle
                $allBundles = $this->kernel->getBundle($bundle, false);
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                return $this->parser->parse($controller);
            }

            foreach ($allBundles as $b) {
                $try = $b->getNamespace().'\\Controller\\'.$controller.'Controller';
                if (class_exists($try)) {
                    // You can also try testing if the action method exists.
                    return $try.'::'.$action;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->parser->parse($controller);
    }

    public function build($controller)
    {
        return $this->parser->build($controller);
    }
}
```

And replace the original service like:

```
actionless_name_parser:
  public: false
  class: My\Namespace\ActionlessNameParser
  decorates: controller_name_converter
  arguments: ["@actionless_name_parser.inner"]
```

Comment: Twifty i think your approach is much better. However foes does symfony know that it suppose to use the new class, where do i register?

Comment: @user1960170, You need to replace the service definition. Look at the link in the answer. When symfony warms the cache, it will always use your new class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Action suffix is here to distinguish between internal methods and methods that are mapped to routes. (According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127250/meaning-of-action-in-symfony-controllers)).

The best way to know for sure is to try.

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/HelloController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class HelloController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Try to remove the Action from the method name and see what happens.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but I question the value of an answer which suggests trying something that is well known to fail.  Almost as though you have not used Symfony 2.

Comment: No I've used Symfony but I used the suffix Action like they said in the docs. I said that because it was an accepted answer in the other post.